# Walkthrough of SnakeYAML in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, configuration-files, snakeyaml

I need to read some values and variables from a .yml file and thats it, write them to a String and thats all I need? How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Map<String, Object> config = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load("Your input");
```

"Your input" can be InputStream, Reader or String.

Comment: This gives me an unchecked cast warning. I could SuppressWarnings, but whats the correct way?